# How to create a page in MVC and link with another page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am beginner in asp.net?
Please tell me how to create a page in mvc and give link with another page.
please give me also a link of mvc to learn more things for beginner.

Thansk & Regards
Vinod Kumar

Answer (score 3):

http://www.asp.net/mvc has a lot of information and tutorials, and is the best starting point for a new ASP.NET MVC developer.

Best of luck with your developement :)